Why would a pension fund use immunization?
According to wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunization_(finance), immunization (i.e. ensuring assets and liabilities are affected similarly by rate movements) is used by pension funds to 'fund a future stream of pension benefit payments to retirees'.
However, the way I understand a pension fund is that the retirees will receive a payout that is already linked to the returns the pension fund can generate via its assets. Isn't that the whole point of the pension fund? You give them money, they invest, and you get an output based on what return they generate?
Thus, the liabilities are not fixed, but floating, based on the returns generated by the pension fund. So what is the point of immunization?

There is (or used to be) a kind of fund called a Defined Benefit Pension fund which promised retirees a specified payoff. That creates a lot of risk for the sponsor who is guaranteeing the return, which could be reduced with immunization. However, nowadays most pension funds are of another kind, which you describe, called Defined Contribution, where the pensioners contribute a specifed sum and the fund provides whatever return it can get, with no guarantees what the payout will be... In that case immunization is not that useful. The sponsor has simply dumped the risk on the pensioners.

In the U.S., many private sector pensions have switched to defined contribution, like 401(k), but many federal / state / non-profit still have defined benefit schemes. See, for example, https://www.ebri.org/docs/default-source/by-the-numbers/ebri_rsrc_facts-and-figures_011923.pdf

Yes, and in Europe also there are many such funds. I exaggerated the Defined Benefit Pension's demise. They are still around and important to know about.
